# Apply custom border size in Spark Textarea using actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

Can it implement border size on the spark textarea using actionscript? If Yes how this is possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
// assuming textArea is initialized Spark TextArea instance
var skin:TextAreaSkin = TextAreaSkin(textArea.skin);
skin.borderStroke.weight = 5;
skin.setElementIndex(skin.border, skin.numElements - 1);
```

This solution should work but it's not reliable - [consider writing own version of `TextAreaSkin` instead](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS53116913-F952-4b21-831F-9DE85B647C8A.html).